# Unexpected conversion of $_GET["var"] to integer

Tags: php, pagination, type-conversion, superglobals, type-coercion

I have the following snippet in a page running under PHP 5.4.10 (notice the === in comparison).

```
$list_all_pages = False;
$reqs_per_page = 50;
$start_page = 0;

if (isset($_GET["p"])) {
    echo("Debug: " . $_GET["p"] . "\n");
    if ($_GET["p"] === "all") {
        $list_all_pages = True;
    } else {
        $start_page = intval($_GET["p"]);
        if ($start_page < 1)
            $start_page = 0;
    }
}
```

The parameter "p" intends to be the number of the results page that will be displayed (starting from zero) or "all" to display all pages.  For reasons I don't understand, PHP automatically converts my parameter to an integer and, as result, I can never display all pages I wish.

For example, calling the page with "`mypage.php?p=all`"  causes the debug echo to print "Debug: 0"

What's happening?  I think this kind of automatic conversion a bit dangerous... does anybody got this problem before?

Comment: are you running this through Wordpress?

Comment: @SamuelCook Are you saying that WP changes the values of the superglobals? :( If that is the case it is even more ff'ed up than I thought :P

Comment: @SamuelCook No, but I have WP installed in the same server and APC is enabled. Can this combination change some global PHP state shared by all Apache processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $_GET variable `p` (ie. ?p=) is reserved in WordPress, as the default way to server up post IDs. While most people like to transform their URLs, the default is www.domain.com/?p=123.

Wordpress specifically looks for this parameter (it is also served as the `wp_shortlink`), and if it is not numeric is will automatically set the value to 0.

Comment: here is a link to the reserved words (terms) in WordPress - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms

Comment: Thanks! I just replaced the "p" with a "pg" and it worked. The problem is: this particular script does not calls any WP function (it does not even run from the same directory). I think there is some global rewrite rule in my Apache configuration messing around with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

this is enough ,no need to type cast

```
if ($_GET["p"] == "all") {
        $list_all_pages = True;
    } else {
        $start_page = (int)$_GET["p"];
        if ($start_page < 1)
            $start_page = 0;
    }
```